# Configuration qualifier for 18:9 aspect ratio screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Not sure if this has been discussed before, but we definitely need a new configuration qualifier for the aspect ratio of the screen. An app can look very different on a 18:9 screen than it looks on a 16:9 screen.

There is an old aspect ratio qualifier (`long` and `notlong`) but that doesn't help since even 16:9 devices fall into the `long` category.

So how do you deal with this issue? Are you using a specific qualifier in your xml layouts? It seems that using the available screen width in combination with the available screen height, we can manage to figure out if the aspect ratio is 18:9 or not, but still this is not ideal.

Does anyone have a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0):

> but we definitely need a new configuration qualifier for the aspect ratio of the screen
>   So how do you deal with this issue?

You can always fall back to calculating display aspect ration in your code and then manually applying layout of your choice while calling `setContentView()`. But I do agree, the qualifier would be the best solution but unless it's there...

Comment: The thing is that I prefer having a single layout file, while getting the values from the dimensions xml. And I'm trying to figure out which qualifier to use in resources, so that the dimensions will apply to 18:9 devices.

Comment: @MScott did you find any solution? I'm googling for a proper qualifier for the same reason for an hour now and nothing useful..

Comment: Ok I just found it. :D Add "-long" to the qualifier. In my case I have multiple layout files (layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi, etc), also I added "layout-sw410dp" for bigger phones (1440x2560). For the 18:9 version which is 1440x2880, I use "layout-sw410dp-long". screenshot: https://ibb.co/fsRm3n

Comment: Unfortunately the `-long` qualifier is not reliable, because it will work even for 16:9 screens. I have tested that and I can confirm that. However, in your example you are also using the `-sw` qualifier, so maybe the combination of these two qualifiers kind of works, but I wouldn't rely on that. What I eventually did is calculating the aspect ratio within my class: `aspectRatio = (metrics.heightPixels + navBarHeight) / metrics.widthPixels;`, where `metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();` and `navBarHeight` is the height of the bottom navigation bar.